# Visual Studio 2013 Compiler issue on Windows phone 8.1 silverlight project

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Today I tried to make a windows phone application, I first stared with universal application and and it worked, emulator was running with project but when I try to use Windows.Phone.Speech namespace I couldn't do that, thus I make some research for it, Then I find the answer I need a windows phone silverlight project. When i'm trying to run a blank windows phone silverlight project I got some error like that

[image: http://prntscr.com/7bidqp]

[image: http://prntscr.com/7bidyd]

I couldn't find anything about it, I compare the csproj with a working wp silverlight project but I couldn't find a difference between them.

Thanks.

Comment: You can keep building a Universal app -- just use the `Windows.Media.Speech*` namespaces instead of the `Windows.Phone.Speech` namespace.

Comment: Is it possible to integrated the cortana on windows 8.1 universal application ? My main goal is make a windows phone application with features cortana. On the other hand, this error isn't seems right. There is no resource about this error on internet. If we can fix it, it will be better for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution about it, but there is still some missing on my answer.

I don't know how but accidentally a blank project worked on my emulator. After that I looked up the **ProjectName.csproj.user** file and there were a change somekind like that

[image: Solution]

After that I added the same lines to another project, and it is worked. The main problem of this solution you need a emulator guid ID. In my solution it was 57B0267A-6444-41EB-9127-2ED594284A2D.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are compiling for Any CPU or specifically for the right kind of CPU that you intend in solution properties.

Comment: Have you set up the licensing issues for publishing your app to the windows store?

Comment: The blank project isn't working how can i publish it ? i'm just pressing F5 on project for emulate it

Comment: You have to manually enter or update several values in the Package.appxmanifest.xml file and the WMAppManifest.xml file. Check this [link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn655122(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: I don't think we can understand each other, I'm not going to publish anything. I'm just trying to run a blank project on visual studio with windows phone emulator.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help, it's just that when I tried to create a new project for windows phone 8.1 it complained about licensing issues. I thought that might be a similar issue.  I hope you find a solution.